# How to make the texture not follow the mesh deformations (Bouncing and stretching ball)

Tags: uv, rigging, texture-coordinates

I want a bone to control the rotation of a ball. But the stretch bone also rotates it, since the texture follows the mesh and stretches and rotates with it. So the texture needs ignore the mesh rotate using the info of the bone only. Currently the texture is using UVs, which I know is stupid so what's the best way to do this?
Here's a screencapture: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dZnNn_P0kz35zvRJni72l8knh07ri2wx/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: hello, it's a little confusing to me, could you please show what the ball and its texture are supposed to do with 2 or 3 drawings/pictures?

Comment: Have you tried with a lattice?

Comment: Yes I tried lattice but it didn't work because rotating it produced some weird twists and stuff.

Comment: your rigging seems complicated, I'm a bit surprised that you need such a complicated rig, what was the problem with lattice, what kind of weird twsit?

Comment: Was the lattice add *after* the armature?

Comment: Once you rotated it beyond a point the lattice started to deform the ball into a cube. The lattice is also cube shaped.

Comment: @lemon no, it was before, I was trying to get the armature control the lattice.

Comment: @Necryl, why before? the lattice should use the transformed vertices, don't you think?

Comment: the lattice would  still deform the ball into a cube without the armature.

Comment: @lemon, that's true but the rig would still rotate it while trying to stretch. Wait guys I have an idea. I'll tell you if it works

Comment: you could create a lattice, hook its 8 vertices to 8 bones, parent both the lattice and armature to the ball, move the ball and deform with the bones?

Comment: I got it working! So basically I found out that once we have a armature controlling the lattice. When rotate that armature in object mode, we don't get any twisting, and the texture doesn't follow the mesh either! So I just made a second armature to rotate the first one and to have the stretch and squash controls. Thank you, your answers gave me the idea. I'll post a link soon in case you wanna see it yourself.

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/en23nWJl/ This is it. After trying to do this for days, it kinda feels like magic that it actually works.

Comment: @Necryl, great! You should write your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

So I got the solution. I used lattice to deform the mesh. However if you rotate the lattice in edit mode, the texture will follow the mesh. But if you rotate the lattice in object mode, the texture doesn't follow the mesh. If you rig some bones to deform the lattice, and have them rotate the lattice as well, the texture will follow the mesh again because the bones seem to rotate lattice points, not the lattice object. However if you rotate this armature in object mode, it will rotate the lattice as object as well. What I did was, I used a second armature to rotate the first and consequently the lattice. I also hooked up the lattice deformation bones in the first armature to copy the location of some bones in the second. This meant I can deform lattice points as well as rotate it as a object in one armature/rig.

I am not the best at explaining so I'll link the files here if you wanna understand how to do this.

Here's the first file that I was struggling with. In this file the texture follows the mesh and is not independent: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/lgJWddwp/

Here's is the file with the problem fixed. In this file the texture doesn't follow the mesh and can be controlled independently from the mesh deformation: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/en23nWJl/