# Rigging: independent squash/stretch

Tags: rigging

I'm new to Blender, coming from Maya. I would like to know whether it's possible to have an independent squash/stretch rig, so that you can apply squash/stretch from any angle, while still having your object oriented the same way (Imagine a ball both able to bounce on the floor and on the wall).
In Maya this would be the squash/stretch nonlinear deformer.

In Blender I have rigged my model to a bone chain with a Stretch To constraint, to get the squashing, and then made a separate control with a Copy Rotation constraint, to be able to rotate my model afterwards.
This works, but requires constant counter animation.

I also tried to put a lattice between the bones and the model, and then rotating the rig in object mode, so the model doesn't get affected by the lattice while rotating.
This also seems to work, but requires switching from pose mode to object mode while animating and I don't know if that's good workflow in Blender.

So none of these solutions are very good. I wonder if somebody knows another way to do it?

Comment: there was a question about bouncing ball here, does it answer? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199711/how-to-make-the-texture-not-follow-the-mesh-deformations-bouncing-and-stretchin

Comment: Thank you, I didn't find that thread before. So I was on the right track with my lattice. It just took another armature and an object level Child Of constraint to make things work in Pose Mode. The only thing bothering me is that now I have to switch between Pose Mode on two separate armatures. Is there a way to have an Object level constraint within one armature? Maybe this should get it's own question though?

Comment: I didn't test the solution he gave so I couldn't answer, but maybe try to show some screenshots and even share your file so that people can understand and test?

Comment: Ok sorry, I was a bit too fast. The solution from the other question works very well. It's a bit mindboggling to be constraining between things in object mode and pose mode at the same time, like diving between different dimensions. But I got it working in the end. I can upload my version if necessary, but it's pretty much identical to the other solution. This can be closed for my part. Thank you!